# Why does `join()` on an array of undefined elements return 1 less element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was initially looking up what happens on `Array.prototype.toString()`. From the spec i realised this calls `.join()`. But I don't understand the output on an array with undefined elements.

`[,,,].toString()` returns `",,"`. But I expected `",,,"`. There appears to be 1 element missing in the serialization. What's happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in JavaScript, the last `,` (the [trailing comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas)) is ignored if it is followed by nothing.

```js
console.log([1,].length);
// -> 1

console.log([1,,].length);
// -> 2
```

Therefore, when you are doing `[,,,]`, the last `,` is ignored. Thus the length is only `3`.

```js
console.log([,,,].length);
// -> 3
```

When you join an array with `n` items, you get `n-1` commas. Hence the result that you are getting.

Comment: Ah. yes i forgot about trailing commas. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Answer (score 3):

The last `comma` in an `array` is optional (for convenience) and therefore ignored in `join()`